# How to choose last several rows of python series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python series and I want to choose the last 5 rows of it. If I use ts[-5:-1],it doesn't return the last rows. How can I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tail.html):

```
s.tail(5)
```

or [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
s.iloc[-5:]
```

Sample:

```
s = pd.Series(range(10))    
print (s)
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
dtype: int32

print (s.tail(5))
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
dtype: int32

print (s.iloc[-5:])
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
dtype: int32
```